# Get text written in Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td class="td1">
<input name="CheckBox" id="c1" type="checkbox" CHECKED="" value="on"/>
<a class="a_c" id="a1">
</td>
```

If I know ID of Check box `$(#c1)` then how can I get text of Anchor tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you have to write a close this tag

```
<input name="CheckBox" id="c1" type="checkbox" CHECKED="" value="on"/>
<a class="a_c" id="a1"> Something </a>
```

Anchor has id assigned yet therefore you can get access directly:

```
$("#a1").text()
```

If anchor did not have id and will be always after checkbox ( can be separated by other tags)

```
$('#c1').next("a").text();
```

otherwise if will be checkbox's sibling and in this branch is one anchor ( not necessarily just after checkbox)

```
 $('#c1').parent().find("a").text();
```

Answer (score 21):

If you are not using jQuery, then below line would help.

```
document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding a pure Javascript answer that doesn't rely on `.innerHTML`, which can be much slower than proper DOM level accessors. This also assumes you are retrieving HTML free content.

Using the original question with a completed a tag:

```
<td class="td1">
<input name="CheckBox" id="c1" type="checkbox" CHECKED="" value="on"/>
<a class="a_c" id="a1">Something wonderful</a>
</td>
```

Javascript using the id from the anchor tag:

```
document.getElementById("a1").textContent;
```

If you need to support Internet Explorer 8 or lower, you'll have to either selectively use `.innerText` for IE 6-8, or stick with `.innerHTML`. `.innerText` was not supported by Firefox for a while, so it shouldn't be used for anything but IE 6-8.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#c1').next("a").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the anchor tag has an ID as in your example, then `$('#a1').text();` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('#c1').next().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
 <a id="ttname">Something Is Beautiful</a>
```

Your Script

```
var Name = document.getElementById("ttname").textContent;  
console.log(Name);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).